# system.entrypointnotfoundexception in <Filename unknown> in Unity3d

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, native-code

I am trying to call a simple native function (C++) from Unity3D. I have done the following:

1. Placed the `libMSDKWrapper.so` in Assets->Plugins->Android
2. This is my C# code

   ```
   using UnityEngine;
   using System.Collections;
   using System.Runtime.InteropServices;

   public class facebooktest : MonoBehaviour {

       [DllImport ("MSDKWrapper")]
       private static extern long getContextNative();

       void Start () {
           Debug.Log("Hello, World!");
           long context = getContextNative(); // <-- Exception thrown here
           Debug.Log(context);
           }
   }
   ```

I am getting the following exception:

> system.entrypointnotfoundexception at [0x00000] in Filename unknown:0

I used the same libMSDKWrapper.so using java using the command

> System.loadLibrary("MSDKWrapper");

and I was able to access and use the getContextNative() method.

Edit 1: I unzipped the contents of the apk and found that libMSDKWrapper.so file is present in test.apk/lib/armeabi-v7a

Edit 2: Here are the logcat logs.
03-25 11:40:17.543: D/dalvikvm(26176): Trying to load lib /data/data/com.disney.citygirl.goo/lib/libMSDKWrapper.so 0x41566348
03-25 11:40:17.568: D/MSDK(26176): Register Provider: SN_COMMUNITY
03-25 11:40:17.568: D/MSDK(26176): Register Provider: SN_FACEBOOK
03-25 11:40:17.568: D/dalvikvm(26176): Added shared lib /data/data/com.disney.citygirl.goo/lib/libMSDKWrapper.so 0x41566348
03-25 11:40:17.568: I/MSDK(26176): JNI_OnLoad called
03-25 11:40:17.573: D/dalvikvm(26176): Trying to load lib /data/data/com.disney.citygirl.goo/lib/libMSDKWrapper.so 0x41566348
03-25 11:40:17.573: D/dalvikvm(26176): Shared lib '/data/data/com.disney.citygirl.goo/lib/libMSDKWrapper.so' already loaded in same CL 0x41566348
03-25 11:40:17.598: I/Unity(26176): System.EntryPointNotFoundException: getContextNative
03-25 11:40:17.598: I/Unity(26176):   at (wrapper managed-to-native) SocialAccess:getContextNative ()
03-25 11:40:17.598: I/Unity(26176):   at SocialAccess.OnClick () [0x00000] in :0 
03-25 11:40:17.598: I/Unity(26176):
03-25 11:40:17.598: I/Unity(26176): (Filename: ./Runtime/ExportGenerated/AndroidManaged/UnityEngineDebug.cpp Line: 43)

Comment: We'd need to see the .dll implementation.  There might be a missing dependency.

Answer (score 2):

You are using a C++ plugin, but maybe your Unity3D version does not support it? I recall you need Pro to do that.

[This page](http://docs.unity3d.com/Documentation/Manual/PluginsForAndroid.html) might provide a solution.

Comment: This was the page that I was following. I have the 30 day evaluation version of unity pro too.

Answer (score 0):

Make sure you are using the extern 'c' directive to avoid [name-mangling issues](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Name_mangling#Name_mangling_in_C.2B.2B). If you don't 'wrap' your calls in 'c' method names, you'll get this exact behavior because the c++ compiler 'mangles' or adds additional architecture-specific 'junk' to the method names. If you have questions, you can refer to my github project [HERE](https://github.com/nterry/39DLL-4-Linux)

Focus on the main.cpp (the entry point which is the same in android-src/ as in the root). That is the pattern you will need to model your c++ dll after. This project will also show you how to build a c++ dll for android. Look at the README for full build instructions for both Ubuntu (and other Debian-like operating systems) and android.

@Virtlink I know its a pro-only feature, but it appears that Unity will just give a warning when using p/invokes. I'm not use if Unity fixed that in V4, but V3 allows you to use them anyways. The trial will also suffice.

Just as another note, is there a specific reason you NEED to use a C++ dll? In almost all cases, you can do what you want in managed C# code. Be absolutely sure you need this DLL as it will break cross-compatibility with a single codebase. With my dll, i decided to scrap my use-case for it and re-wrote the whole thing in c#.